# Flutter: A value of type lib1::Object can't be assigned to a variable of type lib2::Object

Tags: dart, flutter

While trying to compile this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:startup_namer/misc/Constants.dart';
import 'package:startup_namer/ui/question_text.dart';
import '../utils/question.dart';
import '../utils/quiz.dart';
import '../ui/answer_button.dart';
import '../ui/correct_wrong_overlay.dart';

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State createState() => new QuizPageState();
}

//States are mutable
class QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {

    static List<Question> quizQuestions = [
        new Question("5 * 5 = 25", true),
        new Question("4 + 2 = 6", true),
        new Question("4 + 2 = 7", false),
        new Question("Computers don't use energy", false),
        new Question("B is after A in the alphabet", false),
    ];

    Question currentQuestion;
    Quiz quiz = new Quiz(quizQuestions);

    String questionText;
    int questionNumber;
    bool isCorrect, overlayShouldBeVisible = false;


    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this.currentQuestion = this.quiz.nextQuestion;
        this.questionText = this.currentQuestion.aQuestion;
        this.questionNumber = this.quiz.questionNumber;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Stack( 
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
                //Container for tons of stuff (Main page essentially)
                new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new AnswerButton(true,  () => testMe(true)),
                        new QuestionText(this.questionText, this.questionNumber),
                        new AnswerButton(false, () => testMe(false)),
                    ], //<Widget>[]
                ), //Column
                (this.overlayShouldBeVisible) ? new CorrectWrongOverlay(true) : new Container()
            ] //<Widget>[]
        ); //Stack
    }
}

void testMe(bool isTrue){
    if(isTrue){
        print("it is true, huzzah!");
    } else {
        print("it is false, :(");
    }
}
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Error: A value of type 'dart.core::List<#lib1::Question>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dart.core::List<#lib2::Question>'.
```

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBBl1tYkUnE) tutorial series and have checked the code against their Repository but am unable to see what is causing this problem.

Why would I be seeing this casting error if there are no other ambiguous *Question* classes that conflict with it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out the issue had to do with how the imports were being declared up top.

I have not seen this mentioned elsewhere so I will answer the question here. Updating my imports from these:

```
import '../utils/question.dart';
import '../utils/quiz.dart';
import '../ui/answer_button.dart';
import '../ui/correct_wrong_overlay.dart';
```

to these

```
import 'package:startup_namer/utils/question.dart';
import 'package:startup_namer/utils/quiz.dart';
import 'package:startup_namer/ui/answer_button.dart';
import 'package:startup_namer/ui/correct_wrong_overlay.dart';
```

Where I am using the full package declaration as opposed to the shorthand version seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: That only applies for imports in `lib/main.dart` (or whatever entry-point file with `main() {...}` is used. You should be fine everywhere else using relative imports. Also don't import `main.dart` from anywhere.

Comment: Gotcha, so to confirm, since the QuizPage class is declared as the home within the `main.dart` file it applies here, but nested functions that are not directly declared as the `main.dart` will not have that issue?

Comment: One workaround I've found for this is to put the main() method in its own file, and everything else in different files.

Comment: I was having the same issue, and as long as my imports were consistent, i.e. package vs. relative path, everything worked.

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue. Thanks for the answer!