# flutter - A value of type can't be assigned to a variable of type, on similar second method

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building an app within 5 simple steps consuming a API, anyhow, as a newbie on flutter my second step its really similar to the first one witch works perfectly.

So `Error: A value of type '#lib1::UnidadeModel' can't be assigned to a variable of type '#lib2::UnidadeModel'.Try changing the type of the left hand side, or casting the right hand side to '#lib2::UnidadeModel'`
shows on step 2 even after correcting  all `imports` in the project as [Flutter: A value of type lib1::Object can't be assigned to a variable of type lib2::Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913869/flutter-a-value-of-type-ib1object-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-li) instructions, visited many other posts about this problem and I still can't figure what is wrong with my code.

main:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/ui/app.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/ui/passo01.dart';

    void main() => runApp(GtiSesaSaude());

    class GtiSesaSaude extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          systemNavigationBarColor: Color.fromRGBO(41, 84, 142, 1),
        ));

        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'APP.Saúde.SESA',
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            new TransicaoTela(builder: (_) => GtiSesaSaude());
          },
          theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(41, 84, 142, 1)),
          home: new Passo01(),
        );
      }
    }
```

step02:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/blocs/unidade_bloc.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/unidade.model.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/ui/passo03.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/ui/app.dart';

    class Passo02 extends StatelessWidget {
      final String nome;
      final String numero;
      Passo02({@required this.nome, @required this.numero});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(body: Unidade(nome: this.nome, numero: this.numero));
      }
    }

    class Unidade extends StatefulWidget {
      final String nome;
      final String numero;
      Unidade({@required this.nome, @required this.numero});
      @override
      _UnidadeState createState() =>
          _UnidadeState(nome: this.nome, numero: this.numero);
    }

    class _UnidadeState extends State<Unidade> {
      final String nome;
      final String numero;
      var _unidades;
      String _selUnidade;
      _UnidadeState({@required this.nome, @required this.numero});
      final _documento = TextEditingController();

      @override
      void dispose() {
        _documento.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this._getUnidade();
      }

      void _getUnidade() async {
        UnidadeModel unidadeModel = await unidadeBloc.fetchUnidade(); // Error Here
        var unidade = unidadeModel.getUnidades();
        setState(() {
          _unidades = unidade;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        int _unidade;
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Passo 2"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
              actions: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset(
                  "img/logo_icon.png",
                  width: 50,
                )
              ]),
          body: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage("img/passo02.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          this.nome != ""
                              ? this.nome.substring(0, this.nome.indexOf(" "))
                              : "",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Humanist',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 30,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Vamos começar escolhendo da unidade de saúde mais próxima ou a unidade de sua preferência',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Humanist',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 30,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        DropdownButton(
                          hint: new Text('Escolha uma opção:'),
                          value: _unidades == null ? null : _unidade,
                          items: _unidades.map((unidade) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: unidade["numero"].toString(),
                              child: new Text(unidade["nome"].toString()),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selUnidade = newVal;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Humanist',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 30,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {                                
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                new SlideRightRoute(builder: (_) => Passo03()));
                          },
                          elevation: 5.0,
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          //color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 175, 207, 45),
                          color: Colors.purple, //Color.fromRGBO(41, 84, 142, 1),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white70),
                          label: Text(
                            "",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Humanist',
                                fontSize: 30,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ])),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

model:

```
    class UnidadeModel {
    List<_Unidade> _results = [];    

      UnidadeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
        print(parsedJson['unidades'].length);

        List<_Unidade> temp = [];
        for (int i = 0; i < parsedJson['unidades'].length; i++) {
          _Unidade result = _Unidade(parsedJson['unidades'][i]);
          temp.add(result);
        }
        this._results = temp;    
      }  
        List<_Unidade>  getUnidades(){
        return  this._results.isEmpty ? null: this._results;
      }
    }

    class _Unidade {
      String _numero;
      String _nome; 

      _Unidade(result) {
        _numero = result['numero'].toString();
        _nome = result['nome'];   
      }

      String get numero => _numero;
      String get nome => _nome; 

    }
```

bloc:

```
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/resources/repository.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/Unidade.model.dart';
    import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';


    class UnidadeBloc {  
      final _repository = Repository();
      final _unidadeFetcher = PublishSubject<UnidadeModel>();
      Observable<UnidadeModel> get unidade => _unidadeFetcher.stream;


      Future<UnidadeModel> fetchUnidade() async {
        UnidadeModel unidade = await _repository.fetchUnidade();
        _unidadeFetcher.sink.add(unidade);
        return unidade;
      }  

      dispose() {
        _unidadeFetcher.close();
      }
    }

    final unidadeBloc = UnidadeBloc();
```

Repository:

```
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/resources/saude_api.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/paciente.model.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/unidade.model.dart';


    class Repository {    
      final saudeApi = SaudeApi();         
      Future<PacienteModel> fetchPaciente(String documento ) => saudeApi.fetchPaciente(documento);
      Future<UnidadeModel> fetchUnidade() => saudeApi.fetchUnidade();
    }
```

Resource:

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' show Client;
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/paciente.model.dart';
    import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/unidade.model.dart';

    class SaudeApi {
      Client client = Client();

      Future<PacienteModel> fetchPaciente(String documento) async {
        documento = documento.replaceAll('.', '').replaceAll('-', '');
        Map data = documento.length == 11
            ? {"cpf": documento}
            : {"cartao_sus": documento};

        print("entered");
        final response = await client.post(
            "http://172.16.1.33:3010/saude/getPaciente",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: json.encode(data),
            encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
        print(response.body.toString());
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return PacienteModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        } else {
          throw Exception('Erro');
        }    
      }

      Future<UnidadeModel> fetchUnidade() async {
        final response =
            await client.get("http://172.16.1.33:3010/saude/getUnidades",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "content-type": "application/json"
            } );
        print(response.body.toString());
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return UnidadeModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        } else {
          throw Exception('Erro');
        }
      }

    }
```

Difference between Step 01 and 02 are: 01 its a `post`and 02 a `get`  they also have different models and blocs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Flutter version are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it's to do with the way you're importing the model file. Make sure the import for your `Unidade.model.dart` is exactly the same in all files.

In your bloc you have:

`import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/Unidade.model.dart';`

but in your other files you have:

`import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/unidade.model.dart';`

The case matters.

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/Unidade.model.dart';
```

and

```
import 'package:gti_sesa_saude/models/unidade.model.dart';

                                      ^
```

Which causes this issue.
This happens only on Windows because Linux and OSX would not find the file with wrong casing.